# Tabs do not update text inside each tab layout

Tags: java, android, android-activity

The textView which in every tablayout could not be changed to some text.
No errors etc. happen. here is the code.

Each tab layout are in different files .xml.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.coordinators_tab, null,false);
TextView txt = view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);

txt.setText("JUST WE CAN");
```

Please don't dislike this question if  don't understand it!

Comment: I don't see nothing like Tab . Add sufficient code.

Comment: add more explanation and more code.

Comment: res/layout/coordinators_tab.xml

public class CoordinatorsTab extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "CoordinatorsTab";

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.coordinators_tab, container, false);
    }
}

Comment: Pls don't dislike question  if don't want to answer pass it.

Answer (score 1):

Access the views only after the fragment is created.In oncreateview after view is inflated access the views.

```
public class CoordinatorsTab extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "CoordinatorsTab";

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.coordinators_tab, container, false);

        //Access here
        TextView txt = view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        txt.setText("JUST WE CAN");
        return View;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is worked for me my appreciations to u thank U ))

Answer (score 0):

After you find a view you have to cast it like this

```
        TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
```

Comment: Sorry for the misspelling